# ILSR + mathematical precision = perfect book

Tags: machine-learning, references

I very much like the famous "[ILSR](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj-mte4wf7dAhXDDOwKHXdCC4UQFjAAegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww-bcf.usc.edu%2F~gareth%2FISL%2F&usg=AOvVaw0yTjZ30eKBKbv59BIK_wGo)" book by Hastie, Tibshirani et al!

Lots of nice R experiments and good intuitive background is explained - but what the book in my opinion lacks though, is mathematical precision. A number of proofs are simply skipped, or we are only told the theorem in words. No formal justification is given.

Is there any text (book, lecture notes, personal notes, whatever), that is *just like ILSR*, but with the added mathematical precision?
Even better would be some notes accompanying the book, making the mathematical arguments explicit, that in ILSR are often implicit, vague, or missing.

Comment: https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/ is more detailed

Comment: @Tim that's cheating :p. I don't want a much more in-depth treatment (that is as a *side-effect* also *somewhat* more rigorous - but not very much), covering many more models, corner cases etc. I want still want an introductory treatment - but one where the mathematics is pristine. (It can also contain advanced mathematics, like measure theory - I'm not afraid ;))

Comment: But ESL gives you more details on the basic topics and introduces some new ones. I'd also argue that the easy to read books don't include formal math proofs because this would make them not easy to read for the beginners.

Comment: @Tim I'm a beginner in stats - but not in math, where I have a degree. So for me, reading a book that is heavy on math would actually be easier, since I would not be pressed to fill all the gaps myself or spend long hours thinking what the vague statement I just read actually means formally. So from that perspective also ESL would not qualify.

Comment: Maybe "Machine Learning" by Murphy or "Pattern Recognition" by Bishop will suite you

Comment: @Tim Bishop contains more math, but not exactly rigorous maths. So I'd consider it as an intermediate step towards the ideal book I'm looking for. I don't have access to Murphy from where I am now.